# Is "Reason to Believe" correct that other persecuted national didn't survive?

Tags: history, gentiles

(Note: This question has been closed here for being off-topic, so anyone who's interested in this please see https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/69620/what-religions-were-persecuted-and-disappeared-between-1000-bce-1-ce)

R Gottlieb wrote in his book called "Reason to believe" on page 66 that many other cultures (besides Judaism) were persecuted between 1000 BCE - 1 CE, and none survived. (Background: R Gottlieb is trying to show that the survival of the Jews can't be explained by persecution). As far as I'm aware, he does not provide any examples. Does anyone here know of examples (with sources)?

One of the reasons why I'm asking, is because there are different types of "persecution", for example;

1. Long term, limited in harm (eg taxes, ghettos, attacked physically, expelled from geographical location etc)(this is usually a PERSONAL attack on the victim/religion of victim)
2. Short term, potentially fatal (get killed or convert to religion X)(this is usually NOT personal, but rather an attempt to spread the "truth").

Please see my bio (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/28966/tzvi) to see intro to this Q

Comment: Hello. While your question was prompted by a Jewish book, you're seeking information that has nothing to do with Judaism. I suggest a website devoted to world history

Comment: I’m no expert, but the Kingdom of Tyre (the Tyrians) was clearly quite righteous at one time (remember Hiram), and, if Wikipedia is to be believed, may have been persecuted by Assyria for a while. Yet the kingdom was annihilated by the Bayblonians and Persians, as prophesied in Yehezkel 26-28. Hope that gets the ball rolling.

Comment: @robev Got it. Thanks for your suggestion. (I'm new here, so it will probably take me some time to really absorb and understand what questions are appropriate for here)

Comment: @TomW Thank you. I will look into this.

Comment: @Tzvi K - my pleasure. Shavua tov to you :)

Comment: You write "many other cultures (besides Judaism) were persecuted between 1000 BCE - 1 CE, and none survived." <-- That's a bit of a big claim..  He is making the claim. He should provide a list of the cultures of that time and why by 200CE they(According to him) got completely wiped out, completely annihilated.    If there were many peoples that got wiped out, we might not even know of them.  Where are the Ancient Near East writers scratching their heads or explaining how every single culture  from that period, suddenly vanished off the face of the earth. Why did he choose 1CE as his cut off?

Comment: @barlop I agree that it's a big claim. I have sent him an email requesting examples, but he has not replied.  R Gottlieb is claiming that the reason the Ancient Near East writers (or anyone else) are not baffled by this, is because it is highly unusual for a culture to survive persecution - meaning; it was EXPECTED for those cultures to disappear. Judaism is the anomaly - Judaism's survival needs an explanation.  He chose 1 CE because regarding the unexpected survival of Judaism, there are multiple facts to explain in each era - and 1CE was close to the time of the destruction of the temple.

Comment: @TzviK Well just because something is expected doesn't mean people are not baffled by it.  Scientifically and skeptically minded people have expected sunrise and sunset but were still baffled as to what was happening, and questioned it and eventually got their answer about the earth's movements. People that study the ANE would be interested in reasons for ANE peoples dying out even if it were "expected"(if by expected what is meant is seeing it happened and happens, but not knowing why).

Comment: @TzviK You write "there are multiple facts to explain in each era{regarding those cultures disappearing}"  <-- well, I don't think he has provided these facts  e.g. on a per century basis?  Or even in a general sense, it seems he hasn't.  From what you've said he just says they disappeared and we expect them to disappear because that's what they do! That's like an explanation from an average dad or grandpa "Why? Because!"  "Because that's what happens!"

Comment: @barlop (response to comment 1) I do not know WHAT the ANE writers did or didn't write about - please G-d I want to look that up as soon as I find some examples to research.

Comment: @barlop (response comment 2) I apologize for being unclear. What I meant is that R Gottlieb BRINGS multiple facts about JEWISH survival that are unusual and require explanation. I, Tzvi, did not bring them here because they are lengthy - requiring explanations far beyond the few hundred characters allowed by this site (R Gottlieb has a simple version and extended version of these explanation, and even the simple explanation is a few pages long). My goal with my original post was simply to find examples of persecution #1 on cultures that disappeared, and then I was going to research it further.

Comment: Yes you are clear.. I'm saying Gottlieb didn't bring reasons re civilisations that died out.On the subject of Jews surviving... It may b that there r properties of Judaism that allowed it to survive, and that these properties also exist in christianity or islam. For example there are Christians that have been living in islammic lands, heavily persecuted, but have survived. Any religion that has survived 1500 or 2K or 2.5K+ years, is extremely resilient. Maybe the bible had something very unique a powerful story people would die4,, peru urevu,, promises re the future. Meticulous preservation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138331/discussion-between-tzvi-k-and-barlop).